# Quick question regarding order of a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose the order of a group $G$ is $n$, where $n = 2k$ ($k$ is some integer). Consider this argument:

$$r^k = r^{n/2}= (r^n)^{1/2} = (1)^{1/2} = 1.$$

...implying that the order of the group can't be $n.$

I know this argument must fall apart somewhere as, otherwise, no group can have an even order. I am unable to pinpoint, however, exactly where it falls apart. I would appreciate any insight. Thank you!

Comment: Key Question : How do you define the square root of an element of the group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that square roots are not defined aside, concluding that $G$ cannot have order $n$ from the order of each element not being $n$ is fallacious. The infinite direct product $$\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty\Bbb Z_2$$ is a counterexample. A finite counterexample is the Klein four group.

Comment: Ah right. Thank you for the additional (counter)-examples!